# Erro em cálculo de vetor em C

Tags: c

Estou refatorando o meu código para torná-lo mais dinâmico, porém ao incluir a linha `int n = sizeof(vetor)/sizeof(int);` dentro da função `bubble` ele deixou de funcionar corretamente. Onde estou errando?

**Código Modificado**

```
void bubble(int vetor[])
{
    int n = sizeof(vetor)/sizeof(int);
    int k = n;
    int aux;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<k; j++)
        {
            if(vetor[j]>vetor[j+1])
            {
                aux=vetor[j];
                vetor[j]=vetor[j+1];
                vetor[j+1]=aux;
            }
        }
        k--;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int vetor[]={10,3,5,8,1,9,2,4,7,0,6,-1};
    int n=sizeof(vetor)/sizeof(int);

    bubble(vetor);

    printf("\n\n\n");

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",vetor[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Código Original**

```
void bubble(int vetor[],int n)
{
    int k = n;
    int aux;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<k; j++)
        {
            if(vetor[j]>vetor[j+1])
            {
                aux=vetor[j];
                vetor[j]=vetor[j+1];
                vetor[j+1]=aux;
            }
        }
        k--;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int vetor[]={10,3,5,8,1,9,2,4,7,0,6,-1};
    int n=sizeof(vetor)/sizeof(int);

    bubble(vetor,n);

    printf("\n\n\n");

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",vetor[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porque quando você usa um vetor como parâmetro em uma função, no caso o compilador interpreta como um ponteiro. Ou seja isso:

```
void bubble(int vetor[])
```

É o equivalente a isso:

```
void bubble(int *vetor)
```

E aí o `sizeof(vetor)` torna-se `sizeof(int *)` e vai te dar 8, independente de quantos elementos há no vetor.

O motivo disso é que o `sizeof` é resolvido em tempo de compilação, e corresponde a quantidade de bytes em memória que será alocada para armazenar o conteúdo de uma variável. Ele não é determinado em tempo de execução. No caso do código original, o compilador consegue descobrir facilmente quanta memória ele vai precisar para alocar o `vetor`. Já no caso do código modificado, a única coisa que ele vai alocar será um ponteiro, e aí o código vai dar errado.

A solução para isso é reverter ao que era usado no código original. Não confie no uso do `sizeof` para strings, arrays ou listas ligadas, pois frequentemente ele não vai fazer o que se imaginaria que faria.

Veja aqui um teste comprovando isso:

```
int xxx(int vetor[]) {
    return sizeof(vetor);
}

int main() {
    int vetor[] = {10, 3, 5, 8, 1, 9, 2, 4, 7, 0, 6, -1};
    int n = sizeof(vetor) / sizeof(int);
    printf("%d\n", n);
    printf("%d\n", xxx(vetor));
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
12
8
```

[Veja aqui isso rodando no ideone.](https://ideone.com/PgIYuA)

Comment: Victor, obrigada pela informação em relação ao uso do sizeof. Eu não sabia desse problema que pode ocorrer.